# Ease transition when changing image source

Tags: jquery

I have an image that I want to swap out but I'd like to animate or fade in / fade out the transition so its not a  hard swap.  How can I make the transition ease?

HTML

```
<div class="workSample"><a href="various.html"><img class="img" src="images/various.png" alt="Various" style="width:100%"></a></div>
```

and the Javascript

```
$('.img').hover(function(){
    $(this).data('on',
        $(this).attr('src')).attr('src', $(this).data('on').replace(/(\.\w+)$/, "_roll$1")
    );
},function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('on'));
});
```

Comment: While there are other properties (like opacity) on which you can make incremental changes, but source of an image doesn't belong to this category, and therefore, it CAN'T be changed in a gradual manner. Try the approach suggested by @saluce.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and alter the opacity of the img, then perform the swap, then [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to restore the original opacity.

Use the animate callback to perform the swap and re-animate to bring back into view, that way you can guarantee that the image is fully transparent before swapping.